# Java and Eclipse setup properly, how do I install JOGL or LWJGL?

Tags: 3d, opengl, java

I have my Java environment installed alongside Eclipse, and I was successfully able to create and run a new project (simple System.out.println("Yay I work!");

I have the OpenGL SuperBible, and I primarily want to code 3D things (I'll take my time using the book to learn how to draw shapes in 3D space, etc..)

Can you help me get setup with OpenGL in Java? I dont really need LWJGL, although I WILL make games eventually. I just can't even figure out with all of these terrible (and old) tutorials floating around on the net how to install either JOGL or LWJGL.

If you can give me a hand with that, I'd appreciate it. I'd like to feel I contributed by having this page show the answer to the question, so that other poor souls googling for this same information can benefit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about preparing a development environment.

Answer (score 1):

Found a great site which should help with the setup of JOGL http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Jogl_Tutorial#Justin.27s_Getting_Started_with_JOGL_2_Tutorials
and here for LWJGL in Eclipse:
http://lwjgl.org/installation.php#eclipse

Comment: I have tried to follow the guide for JOGL2 set up in eclipse, but the download it links dose not seem to match up with the instructions in the tutorial. for example, gluegen-rt is actually gluegen-gl. Do you know of an updated version of this tutorial that could help?

Answer (score 1):

Full up to date LWJGL instructions and tutorials can be found on the LWJGL Wiki http://wiki.lwjgl.org/ this includes how to set it up with Eclipse, Netbeans, etc and has tutorials that cover the basics of LWJGL.

Answer (score 0):

i found a nice resourve at http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/opengl/JOGL2.0.html. it shows how to make an eclipse user library from the downloads.